# Java 8. Thread synchronization issue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have three objects: A, B, and C. 
I need such synchronization so that blocks synchronized with objects A and B can be executed in parallel, and when block synchronized with objects A or block synchronized with objects B is executed,  block synchronized with objects C cannot be executed. And when  block synchronized with objects C is executed,  blocks synchronized with objects A and B cannot be executed. I tried to use object C as list, and objects A and B as objects stored in this list, but it did not work. Please tell me, is it possible to somehow configure such synchronization?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Threads {
    public List<Res> lst = new ArrayList();

    public void startThreads(){
        lst.add(new Res());
        lst.add(new Res());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new work1());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new work2());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new work3());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
    public class work1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Method1();
        }
    }
    public class work2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             Method2();
        }
    }

    public class work3 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Method3();
        }
    }

    public void Method1(){
        synchronized (lst.get(0)/*obj A*/){ 
            //some work
        }
    }

    public void Method2(){
        synchronized (lst.get(1)/*obj B*/){
            //some work
        }
    }

    public void Method3(){
         synchronized (lst)/*obj C*/{
            //some work
        }
    }
}
```

Class Res:

```
public class Res {
    public int number = 0;
}
```

Class Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Threads t = new Threads();
        t.startThreads();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your case simplest (Not recommended) solution is to guard Block A and Block B with different monitor objects and guard Block C with the monitor obects of both A and B.

```
public void Method1(){
    synchronized (A){
        //some work
    }
}

public void Method2(){
    synchronized (B){
        //some work
    }
}

public void Method3(){
    synchronized (A){
        synchronized (B){
            //some work
        }
    }
}
```

Same can be done using [Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) as well.

```
public void Method1(){
    lockA.lock();
    try{
        //some work
    } finally {
        lockA.unlock();
    }
}

public void Method2(){
    lockB.lock();
    try{
        //some work
    } finally {
        lockB.unlock();
    }
}

public void Method3(){
    lockA.lock();
    try{
        lockB.lock();
        try{
            //some work
        } finally {
            lockB.unlock();
        }
    } finally {
        lockA.unlock();
    }
}
```

Or you can use read/write lock as suggested by shmosel in the comments.

```
public void Method1(){
    readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
    try{
        //some work
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

public void Method2(){
    readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
    try{
        //some work
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

public void Method3(){
    readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
    try{
        //some work
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

<strike>You can also use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for the same purpose, though read/write lock is the easiest one.</strike>

Comment: The double lock is not equivalent to the read/write lock. It won't allow concurrent access to A or to B. Not sure which one OP actually needs. Why do you say the second example is more efficient though? Also, I don't see how CountDownLatch is relevant. Did you mean Semaphore?

Comment: From the question I understand that A,B block should be independent of each other while C and (A/B) should be dependent. So If lockA is locked, B can run but C can't and when C is running both lockA and LockB are in use by it so A, B can't run. Now when I think about it, CountDownLatch is for one time use only and it won't work. Regarding the Lock performance, I remember watching a video where it was discussed. Basically whenever synchronized is used it affects whole Thread state in the stack, while Lock affects only relevant code. I will try to find the link and put that here.

Comment: Re, "Same can be done more efficiently using Locks," The relative efficiency of explicit `Lock` objects vs. `synchronized` statements is an implementation detail.  Explicit `Lock` objects are more _powerful_ (i.e., you can do things with them that you can't do with `synchronized` statements), but there is nothing about how they are defined that makes them inherently more efficient.

Comment: You're right, I was confusing `volatile` effect with `synchronized` effect. Updated answer.